# Qml scroll doesn't obey to Windows Mouse Settings

Tags: qt, scroll, qml

From the default Qt 5.12.4 - "Qt Quick Qpplication - Scroll" with model edited from 20 into 200.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Scroll")

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            width: parent.width
            model: 200

            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                text: "Item " + (index + 1)
                width: parent.width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Changing "Choose how many lines to scroll each time" has immediate effect in Qt Creator as well as in most browsers and others apps but takes no effect in here.

[image: Mouse settings screenshot]

How can I make my application behaves like others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in the Qt documentation I found the following possible workaround.

Firstly, you need to determine the mouse setting in your windows control panel using the `QStyleHints` of your app. Then you need to transfer the `wheelScrollLines` property to your qml component.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QStyleHints>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QVariant>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();
    auto scrollLines =QVariant::fromValue(app.styleHints()->wheelScrollLines());
    qDebug() << scrollLines;
    context->setContextProperty("scrollLines", scrollLines);
    engine.load(QUrl("./data/main.qml"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Inside your qml component it will be where the real fun starts. You need to set the properties `flickDeceleration` and `maximumFlickVelocity` depending on your `scrollLines` and your Item Delegates Height.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no documentation that gives you the exact amount on pixels going to be scrolled given these two properties. So that one has to rely on guessing or debugging inside the Qt framework. In case the velocity in pixels/seconds changes it is written on the console. This might give you a clue.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Scroll")

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            width: parent.width
            model: 200
            property double pixelsToScroll: 100*scrollLines

            flickDeceleration: -0.5*(maximumFlickVelocity*0.25)*(maximumFlickVelocity*0.25)/pixelsToScroll
            onVerticalVelocityChanged : console.log(verticalVelocity)
            maximumFlickVelocity: 2000 // Pixels per Second??? maximumFlickVelocity*0.25 seems to be the initial velocity
            delegate: ItemDelegate {            
                text: "Item " + (index + 1)
                width: parent.width
                height: 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Effectively, QStyleHints::wheelScrollLines returns value I need. However, respective signal isn't being emitted (at least in Windows 10). Any suggestion? PS: I would avoid a timer to read again...

Comment: @NunoRafaelFigueiredo: So, you are looking for a signal being emitted, whenever the user changes the settings?

Comment: @NunoRafaelFigueiredo: Try the signal `wheelScrollLinesChanged(int scrollLines)` emitted by `QStyleHints`. It is in the documentation.

Comment: 1) yep; 2) I tried; it did't work. In my previous comment, I was calling it wheelScrollLines respective signal...

Comment: @NunoRafaelFigueiredo: I also tried it. It seems to be broken. The signal is also not sent on Windows7. Only workaround is constant polling of the property and to submit a ticket to Qt. :-)